# Correct key-serializer to use for kafka avro

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

If I use `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` in my `key-serializer` attribute yml file, the key that gets published in Kafka is correct but I get the SerializationException error : `Error deserializing Avro message for id -1` when that message is consumed.

But when I use `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer` instead, I don't get the SerializationException error but there are leading characters that gets added with the key. The characters are `\u00014H` and I have no idea where they came from. I'm using UUID as key and the application is in Spring Boot.

What should be the proper serializer to use? The value-serializer I use is `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

> The characters are \u00014H and I have no idea where they came from

They came from you using String **Deserializer** when you're consuming the Avro bytes.

If you only have UUID strings, then you don't need Avro. Kafka has its own UUIDSerializer

Comment: I don't think it is because of the String Deserializer because the message was not consumed yet at that time. What I'm talking about is the message key that gets displayed  in the Control Center site. I'm bothered by those extra characters but the messages are consumed without any issues.

Comment: Control Center only shows strings. It is consuming the data. Use `kafka-avro-console-consumer` instead